# What part do I have to change if

Tags: php, jquery, html

I use a ready template for Joomla. On each page there is a 5-picture-slide-part included. In HTML it looks like:

```
        <div id="slide">
           <div id="faded">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                        <li><img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                        <li><img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                        <li><img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>

                    <ul class="pagination">
                            <li> <a href="#" rel="0"> <img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide1-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#" rel="1"> <img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide2-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="#" rel="2"> <img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide3-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="#" rel="3"> <img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide4-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#" rel="4"> <img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/slide5-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                    <div id="newsflash">
                         <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="xhtml" />
                    </div>
            </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                     var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
                         $j(function(){
                         $j("#faded").faded({
                                speed:<?php echo $speed ?>,// 900,
                                crossfade: true,
                                autopagination: false,
                                autoplay: <?php echo $autoplay ?>,//default 5000,
                                autorestart: true
                         });
                     });
                </script>
                    <div id="tool">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="login" /> 
                    </div>
```

What part do I have to change, to get this picture-slide only at the font page instead of each page. Sorry I'm a beginner in writing HTML and PHP...

Regards, Eva

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following code to check if you are browsing frontpage.

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
        echo 'This is the front page';
}
?>
```

So your slideshow code has to be in place of: `echo 'This is the front page';`.

Full details could be found at: [How to determine if the user is viewing the front page](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page)

Comment: Hi Emmanuel,
thanks a lot for your help. But I'm a really bloody beginner. Which part of the script shall I put instead of "echo...."

I just get an error :(

Regards, Eva

Comment: You have to add slideshow part `<div id="faded"> ... </div>` adding a closing php tag before `?>` and an opening one after `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the slider only on the front page you have to delete that shows the slider on all the templates except the frontpage (all the faded div).

Comment: Hi Azucena,
thanks a lot. That will work. But please have a look at www.hellp4u.org
There is a white field with the slider. The text is below. What I want is, the white board with the slider on the frontage, on all other pages only the text und the search field below the text. Can u imagine?

Comment: Now I put this before the script above:



<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
        
echo 'This is the front page';

}
?>